# React Native Barcode Generator

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently building a `React Native Mobile Apps` and need to generate a **`barcode`** based on some numbers.

Is there any working libraries that I can use?

- I have tried the `react-native-barcode-builder` (source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-barcode-builder). But that's no use because I'm unable to link the `react art`. There is no `ART.xcodeproj` in node-module directory
- I have tried the `react-native-1d-barcode` (source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-1d-barcodes) but it always get an error about `WebView` that's no longer supported in React-Native

Please tell me if there is any solution that I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer.

I'm using the `React Native Barcode Builder` now. Just manage to fix the ART issue by following the answer in here https://github.com/oblador/react-native-progress/issues/127

after that, everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Actually Art library is moved from react native package to [react native community/art](https://github.com/react-native-community/art)

After install art library ART.xcodeproj is located in path node_modules/@react-native-community/art/ios/